# Differentiating under the (Lebesgue) integral sign.

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

There's this guide for proving the theorem about differentiation under integral sign, I took a look around some questions here, but I still have doubts. I know I can probably find this done in a book, but I'm so close that I'd rather ask here instead.

> Let $(Y, {\scr A},\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(Y) < +\infty$, $U \subseteq \Bbb R^N$ open, and $f\colon U \times Y \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x, \cdot)$ is $\scr A$-measurable and bounded, for all $x \in U$, so we can define $F(x) = \int_Y f(x,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y)$.
>
> (a) If $f(\cdot, y)$ is continuous for all $y \in Y$ and $|f(x,y)| \leq M$ for all $(x,y) \in U \times Y$ for some $M  \geq 0$, then $F$ is continuous.

Let $x_0 \in U$ and take $(x_n)_{n \geq 1} \subseteq U$ such that $x_n \to x_0$. Let's prove that $F(x_n) \to F(x_0)$. By continuity of $f(\cdot, y)$, we have that $x_n \to x_0$ implies that $f(x_n,y) \to f(x_0, y)$. Since $|f(x,y)| \leq M$, we have that $\int_Yf(x_n,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y) \to \int_Y f(x_0,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y)$, but that's what we wanted.

> (b) Suppose now that $f(\cdot, y)$ is $C^1$ in $U$ for all $y \in Y$ and that $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x,y)\right| \leq M_1$ for all $(x,y) \in U \times Y$ for some $M_1 \geq 0$. Show that $F$ is $C^1$ in $U$ and: $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x,y) = \int_Y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y),$$for all $x \in U$, $j=1,2,\ldots, N$.

We can suppose without loss of generality that $N=1$, so we want to prove that $F'(x) = \int_Y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y)$ here. I also know that once we prove that $F'$ is given by that formula, the proof from (a) applies with $F' \leftrightarrow F$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \leftrightarrow f$, so that $F'$ being continuous is a given.

We have to prove the formula, then. All the versions of this exercise I've seen so far or uses some uniform continuity, which I don't have here, or the integral is over $[0,1]$, allowing the ${\rm stuff} = \int_0^1 {\rm stuff}\,{\rm d}y$ step. I only know that $\mu(Y) < +\infty$, not that $\mu(Y) = 1$. The natural thing to do was to use the MVT: \begin{align}\left|\frac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{x-x_0} - \int_Y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y)\right| &= \left|\frac{f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)}{x-x_0} - \int_Y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y)\right| \\ &= \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi, y) - \int_Y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y)\right|,\end{align} for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $x_0$, and I can't do anything from here on. Now what?

Comment: $$\frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \frac{1}{x-x_0} \int_Y f(x,y) - f(x_0,y)\,d\mu(y),$$ you have the integral there that you need.

Comment: Man, I'm stupid. How come I missed an entire integral? Let me try again here. Thanks.

Comment: Welp, I got: $$\left|\frac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{x-x_0} - \int_Y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)\,{\rm d}\mu(y)\right| \leq \int_Y \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi, y)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)\right|\,{\rm d}\mu(y)$$using MVT again, but I don't have uniform continuity here..

Comment: Who needs uniform continuity? You have the dominated convergence theorem. Use it.

Comment: Like I did in (a)? Just to be sure I got it: start with a sequence $x_n \to x_0$, then use MVT to get another sequence $\xi_n \to x_0$, and apply $\lim_{n \to +\infty}$ in both sides above, using the dominated convergence theorem to swap $\lim$ and $\int$ in the right side?

Comment: Sort of. Be aware that $\xi_n$ depends on $y$ too, so you must be a bit careful what you write down. But mostly, it's the same argument as in a).

Comment: If $\xi_n$ is a measurable function of $y$ then ok. But this seems tricky. If I note that $\xi_n(y) \to x_0$ *for all* $y \in Y$ is it sufficient? I'm unsure.

Comment: You don't need to consider $\xi_n$ in detail. Under the strong hypotheses here, it suffices to know they exist. That gives you $\bigl\lvert \frac{f(x_n,y) - f(x_0,y)}{x_n - x_0}\bigr\rvert \leqslant M_1$ for all $n$ and all $y$. Then the pointwise convergence of $\frac{f(x_n,y) - f(x_0,y)}{x_n - x_0}$ to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)$ gives you the desired conclusion.

Comment: Ok. I managed it here. Thanks again for the patience. (if you want to convert your comments to an answer in topics or whatever, I'll be glad to accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is quite similar to the proof of part a). We consider a sequence $x_n \to x_0$ such that $x_n \neq x_0$ for all $n > 0$, and the difference quotient

$$\frac{F(x_n) - F(x_0)}{x_n - x_0} = \int_Y \underbrace{\frac{f(x_n,y) - f(x_0,y)}{x_n - x_0}}_{g_n(y)}\,d\mu(y).$$

By the mean value theorem, for every $n$, and every $y$, there is a $\xi_n(y)$ between $x_n$ and $x_0$ such that

$$\frac{f(x_n,y) - f(x_0,y)}{x_n - x_0} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi_n(y),y),$$

so we have the bound $\lvert g_n(y)\rvert \leqslant M_1$ for all $n$. By the partial differentiability of $f$, we have $g_n(y) \to \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)$ for all $y$. The dominated convergence theorem thus yields

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{F(x_n) - F(x_0)}{x_n - x_0} = \int_Y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)\,d\mu(y).$$

Since the sequence $(x_n)$ was arbitrary, that means $F$ is differentiable and

$$F'(x_0) = \int_Y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)\,d\mu(y).$$

Part a) then yields that $F$ is continuously differentiable.